# How to save all listbox items to access database with comma(",") as separator in one row

Tags: vb.net, listbox, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a vb.net application which saves the patient's history of illness to database. but i am stuck at how am i gonna save all listbox items to a single row (using comma as separator).
 I tried using this code but it only saves the last record:

```
 Dim diagnosis As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To txtDiagnosis.Items.Count - 1
            diagnosis = String.Concat(txtDiagnosis.Items(i), ",")
        Next
            'Insert Query Here
```

I also wanted the last record not to have a comma after it. Thanks in advance

Comment: This violates the [first normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Use a second table with a 1:n relationship instead.

Comment: @Heinzi what do you mean it violates first normal form? i just want to save all listbox items to database with comma(,) as separator for example i have 3 items in my listbox
Item1
Item2
Item3
i want to save those items to database as:
Item1,Item2,Item3

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article I linked to?

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Join` function. [String.Join(Of T) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim diagnosis As String = String.Join(", ", txtDiagnosis.Items)
```

You can convert items to the collection of strings

```
Dim allDiagnosis = txtDiagnosis.Items.Select(Function(item) item.ToString())
Dim diagnosis As String = String.Join(", ", allDiagnosis)
```

For `ListBox.Items` you need explicitly cast collection to collection of objects

```
Dim allDiagnosis = txtDiagnosis.Items.
                                Cast(Of Object)().
                                Select(Function(item) item.ToString())
Dim diagnosis As String = String.Join(", ", allDiagnosis)
```

Comment: i got this error using that method (Late-bound extension methods are not supported)

Comment: @ronstoppable, what is the type of `txtDiagnosis.Items`?

Comment: I dont know what does that mean. but im using listbox on visual studio 2010. i've tried your codes above but it gave me this errors:
`Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String'.` and `'Select' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'.`